# How to set cookies with microservice nest js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nestjs, microservices

I have one authentication service and one api gateway
All api request are go through api gateway,
problem :
i cannot able to set cookies in authentication service

```
@post('/signin')
signin(@Body() body:any,@Res({passthrough:true}) res:Response) 
{
return this.appService.signin(body,res);
}
```

This is my api gateway app-controller

```
signin(body,res)
{
const pattern = { cmd: 'signin' };
return this.clientServiceA.send<any>(pattern,{body,res})
}
```

This is api gateway's service and
this will send request to authentication service api

```
export class AppController {
@MessagePattern({ cmd: 'signin' })
signin(body,res) {
 res.cookie('jwt',token,{httpOnly:true,expires:new Date(Date.now()+1000*60*60*24*7)});
// i cannot able to use res here it will throw an error
return {
status:200,
message:'login success'
}
}
```

Above mentioned code is for authentication controller.I can't able to use res.cookies there.
How can i use res.cookies inside this auth service?
anyone knows please help i am very new to micro service architecture

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@Res` decorator.

```
signin(body, @Res() res: Response)
```

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/cookies